# Round x to the nearest integer in "asked x year(s) ago"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, timestamps

It always throws me off whenever I see a question that was "asked 1 year ago" and then realize it was actually asked nearly 2 years ago.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093688/how-to-create-range-in-swift):

[image]

When `x` is greater than `1` year, can we round it to the nearest integer?

Or else include the months:

```
asked  1 year and 11 months ago
```

Comment: Not just years. Also hours etc. And there's "yesterday", which means 24 to 47 hours ago. Anyway, it threw me off at first, but now I'm used to it. There are aspects about this site that bother me more.

Comment: *It always throws me off ...*  Seriously ?   Me, I think it's a member of the set of `SO-world problems` which itself is a very small subset of `first-world problems`.

Comment: If it is rounded to the nearest integer you just know someone is going to be bothered by the fact that it states 2 years ago when it is in fact slightly less than 2 years. If it needs fixing, make it accurate.

Comment: I think I had the same problem in the beginning. I just started ignoring the "1 year ago" information and I always look at the exact date instead.

Comment: The feature was added--I can only guess--because someone thought it would be more useful than just looking at the standard formatted time-stamp.  If it's ignored then just get rid of the feature... but apparently it remains because an alternate time representation is still useful... and so is still subject to improvement.  High Performance Mark's comments are completely useless since at some level the same could be said about the entire Stack Exchange community.  Is there a badge for having high reputation and still spamming with completely unhelpful comments?

Comment: What do you mean round to the nearest integer? 1.5 years ago is not an integer value.

Comment: I don't think the thing is really that necessary to have two different locations that tell you two different times. This value on this question just says "today" but below the post in your user card it says "asked 15 hours ago". Why not just put the exact timestamp in the card and at the top?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark is included on those the use of backticks for non-code?

Comment: just have it say "asked a looooooooong time ago."

Comment: Why is the same information stated twice anyway? Just remove it from the sidebar.

Comment: @All: `heck yes'

Comment: Whenever the number is less than some threshold (2? 3?) move to the next unit. ("400 days" is better than "1 year" or "2 years")

Comment: Solution: "Over 1 year ago"

Comment: "You've slept since this question was asked." Problem solved.

Comment: The message is not accurate (and it misses by a long shot). It sounds like a bug rather than a feature request.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Unless someone's accessing SO from a third world country, in which case they could become a subset of unimportant third world problems.

Comment: why not simply have the number showing 1 decimal place, it's what i do on my website and works pretty neatly. `1.8 years ago` would suit (imho) perfectly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Date formatting is vexing because of so many hidden traps like [pluralization rules across languages](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) which require special handling for many cases. That and the fact that we re-use common formatting code in multiple places, sometimes because of layout constraints (in some places, horizontal space is a premium).

That said, the existing issue was indeed annoying, and we already have translations in place for "X years, Y months ago", so I made the change. This also applies to a few other areas, e.g., Tag Wikis and certain Review Queues.

Months may still seem off by 1 if you really do the math (e.g., 1 year, 4 months and 28 days ago is still just 1 year, 4 months ago), but the purpose is to give a feel for the timeframe, and that should be the case now.

Comment: Yay! I never expected such a fast response. Thanks a lot! This will make it obvious at a glance how old the question is.

Answer (score 28):

Rather than rounding or cluttering it up with an exact number of months (or days!), I have an alternate suggestion.

If it is over one month from the yearly anniversary, change the text from "1 year ago" to "over 1 year ago".

This avoids the complaints that would come from people annoyed that 1.5 years gets rounded to 2.

Comment: "nearly 2 years ago" :D

Comment: @Cœur basically kinda low-key two years ago...soon.

Comment: "more than 1 year ago and getting close, but not that close, to 2 years ago"

Comment: Use a bar to show how old it is. The bar should be in the shape of a tree. Obviously, the older the tree, the older the question. When you hover over the bar there should be an animation sawing off the tree and then a magnified view of the trunk - so you can count the rings.

Comment: Just change the text to "over 0 years ago". Problem solved.

Comment: @GolezTrol a statement can be both truthful and unhelpful at the same time. I think we're trying to move in the direction of *more* helpful.

Comment: "This question was asked x years ago where 2 > x > 1."

Comment: Why not using month part too? "1 year 11 months ago" makes sense for me. Honestly I didn't notice that "year" part, prefer directly viewing exact date instead (i.e. May 7 '15).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto did you see the part about "cluttering it up with an exact number of months"? You should upvote the answer by Michael Stum which I just noticed.